# Upgrading Rails Versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, updates

I know that to update Rails, you update the version number in your `Gemfile` and then `bundle update` but what I am getting confused about is how do you know if anything else has changed?

How do I know if there are config options to add or anything else anywhere. Contents of files or whole directories.

Any clues?

Comment: This is where you rely on good test coverage. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails upgrades fall into the following categories;

1. Patch version upgrades (e.g., 3.2.10 to 3.2.11)
2. Minor version upgrades (e.g., 3.1.X to 3.2.X)
3. Major version upgrades (e.g., 3.X.X to 4.X.X)

#### Major/Minor Upgrades

Major and minor version upgrades require a lot of work, and I'd urge you to look out for screencasts from people like Peepcode or Peter Cook.

Sometimes its easier to do a `rails new` and copy all the initializers and config files over the top of your app, and do a diff to find what's changed.

I'd always suggest doing a minor version at a time.

For example, if you are still on 2.3.x, you should first upgrade to 3.0.x, then the 3.1.x, then to 3.2.x

#### Patch Upgrades

Patch version upgrades are generally simpler (and important since they often include security fixes).  Look out for any deprecation notices in your logs, and fix the changes.

Do a Gemfile update, run your tests, and most of the time it'll be fine.

Comment: No problem.  I would also point to http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/releases/ as a good reference.

Answer (score 1):

It certainly depends on which versions you're upgrading between. In general, Rails does a pretty good job documenting what you'd need to change in the release notes, for example: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/3_2_release_notes.html

Sometimes, deprecation notices will help you after you upgrade. Alternatively, you can `rails new` a brand new app, and compare configuration files of the clean-slate app with your existing one.

Answer (score 1):

The [Railsdiff.org](http://railsdiff.org) site can provide the difference between the contents of a vanilla Rails project (ie as if running `Rails New`) between any two versions of Rails going back to `3.0.0`. I find this particularly useful to determine if there have been any changes to the standard configuration options between versions or if there are new files added/removed from a standard project which you may want to copy over to your existing project.

This won't provide any insight into what has changed in the framework itself, for that you'll need to jump into the change logs for each release. Easiest way to pick them up is check out the [Ruby on Rails blog](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org) which includes notes and links for each released version.